# how do i read data from Ms Word document using perl module in linux support

Tags: perl, module, ms-word

How do I read data from MS Word document using Perl module in linux support

Answer (score 3):

Text::Extract::Word [looks like it might be a good place to start.](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aExtract%3a%3aWord) From the synopsis:

```
# object-based interface
use Text::Extract::Word;
my $file = Text::Extract::Word->new("test1.doc");
my $text = $file->get_text();
my $body = $file->get_body();
my $footnotes = $file->get_footnotes();
my $headers = $file->get_headers();
my $annotations = $file->get_annotations();
my $bookmarks = $file->get_bookmarks();

# specify :raw if you don't want the text cleaned
my $raw = $file->get_text(':raw');

# legacy interface
use Text::Extract::Word qw(get_all_text);
my $text = get_all_text("test1.doc");
```

Answer (score 0):

I use OLE for Word, Excel, and Outlook:

```
require Win32::OLE;
$docfile = "C:\\something.doc";
$Word = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Word.Application');
unless ($Word) { $Word = Win32::OLE->new('Word.Application', sub {$_[0]->Quit;}) or die "oops\n"; }
$Word->{visible} = 1;
my $File = $Word->Documents->Open($docfile);
$File->PrintOut();
$File->Close(); 
$Word->Quit();
undef $File;
undef $Word;
```

Comment: OP asks for "in linux support" (?). Win32::OLE on linux is unsupported.

Comment: Quick question: why the `$File->PrintOut()`? Isnt' that printing the file?