# How to read content from a MS Word file using Perl

Tags: perl

I have a scenario where I need to look for some heading title from 2 MS Word doc(x) files and need to update the third one (which is again a MS Word file).

To create MS Word file CPAN modules are there, but is there any CPAN modules to read it and manipulate the content accordingly?

Comment: See [Converting .docx files to plain text and preserving line breaks to maintain line number references to source document: howto & implications?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145230/converting-docx-files-to-plain-text-and-preserving-line-breaks-to-maintain-line) and [How can I read the .docx file in perl?](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1029093)

Comment: I am using Linux and I am able to create a docx file but I am not able to read a docx file using available CPAN modules.

Answer (score 0):

From a quick google I've found the following solutions:

[Using Win32 modules](http://www.wellho.net/solutions/perl-using-perl-to-read-microsoft-word-documents.html)

[Using Text::Extract::Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15616132/how-do-i-read-data-from-ms-word-document-using-perl-module-in-linux-support)

Comment: Note: `Win32::OLE` can not be used on Linux.

Comment: Also tested `Text::Extract::Word` on Linux to read a `.docx` file, but got error `"This does not seem to be a Word document, but it is pretending to be one"`. Maybe this module cannot read `.docx`?

Comment: @HåkonHægland agreed with your comments (y)